# Overwriting Bootstrap Tooltip CSS causes padding to be transparent, but not content

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm working on getting my sites code up to speed on some css changes, in particular to the tooltips.  Do to some contraints, the decision was made to overwrite the bootstrap CSS, rather than have a new one created.  During this process, I'm seeing some strange behaviour, where the content of the tooltip is opaque at 1, but the padding is not.  This causes the padding portions to show text coming through, where I want the whole thing to be opaque ...

This is occuring in IE (Edge) and Chrome browsers.

I've recreated this in jsfiddle for visibility and code.
https://jsfiddle.net/s923y9a4/1/

Heres some relevant CSS (rest is on fiddle):

```
 /* START Overwrite bootstrap tooltips */

.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1070;
  display: block;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  text-align: left;
  text-align: start;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: none;
  text-transform: none;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  word-break: normal;
  word-spacing: normal;
  word-wrap: normal;
  white-space: normal;
  padding: 12px;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
  color: #4b4b4b;
  line-break: auto;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.tooltip.in {
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  opacity: 1;
}

.tooltip.right {
  padding: 12px;
  margin-left: 3px;
}

.tooltip-inner {
  max-width: 200px;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.tooltip-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  z-index: 1000;
}

.tooltip.right .tooltip-arrow {
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: -15px;
  /*border-width: 15px 15px 15px 0;*/
  border-right-color: #fff;
}
/* END Bootstrap Tooltip overwrite */
```

I've tried everything I can think of, so if you have any ideas I'd be very appreciative for the help!

P.S. There is also some work to be done on the tooltip arrow, but I haven't spent as much time on that as this.  If you happen to have quick fix for that, I certainly won't turn it away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a background color to the base .tooltip.  Since you have not assigned a background color, the padding has no color, and thus, is opaque.

```
.tooltip {
    background-color: #fff;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Well done sir!  Seems it was the most basic thing I took for granted.  Thanks very much!